# PHP & XML - How to generate a soap request error 415

Tags: php, xml, curl, soap

Why am I getting error 415, if anyone can help me
I do not understand why the error occurs
link to error
http://agency.lastminute-hr.com/stranice/upisi_destinacije_unico.php

This is how the xml

```
POST /services/WebService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: wl.filos.com.gr
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <soap12:Body>
        <PlaceSearch xmlns="http://www.cyberlogic.gr/webservices/">
          <xml>string</xml>
        </PlaceSearch>
      </soap12:Body>
    </soap12:Envelope>
```

my code is:

```
$soapUrl = "http://wl.filos.com.gr/services/WebService.asmx?op=PlaceSearch";



$soap_request  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n";
  $soap_request .= "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n";
  $soap_request .= " <soap:Body>\n";
  $soap_request .= "  <PlaceSearch xmlns=\"http://www.cyberlogic.gr/webservices/\">\n";
  $soap_request .= "  <xml><PlaceSearchRequest><Username>******</Username><Password>******</Password><PlaceType>Cities</PlaceType><Language>en</Language></PlaceSearchRequest></xml>\n";
  $soap_request .= "   </PlaceSearch>\n";
  $soap_request .= "  </soap:Body>\n";
  $soap_request .= "</soap:Envelope>";
 $xml_post_string  =  $soap_request;



$headers = array(
"POST /services/WebService.asmx HTTP/1.1",
"Host: wl.filos.com.gr",
"Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",
"Content-Length: ".strlen($xml_post_string)
); 




$url = $soapUrl;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  ($xml_post_string) );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch); 

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);

     // echo results
        echo "The server responded: <br />";
        echo   " " .  $info['http_code'].  "  <br />";

curl_close($ch);        
$response1 = str_replace("<soap12:Body>","",$response);
$response2 = str_replace("</soap12:Body>","",$response1);

$parser = simplexml_load_string($response2);
```

Comment: How is this different from your own and already asked question? 415 is the code for unsupported media-type. You have to create the request XML data in a format that is accepted by the webservice end-point. You still don't do so. The documentation of the webservice *with* XML examples is here: http://wl.filos.com.gr/services/WebService.asmx?op=PlaceSearch - even with some testing facility.

Answer (score 1):

415 is the *HTTP Status Code* you obtain from the response of the HTTP request you fire with curl.

These codes are [standardized and documented](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), in your case of 415:

> **415 Unsupported Media Type**
>
> The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

The *entity of the request* means the request-body, which is the POST method's request body. In short this means, that the data you've send to the server does not fit it's needs.

You have to fix the data you send to the server first, otherwise all later operations (like loading the response string into simplexml) will fail as well.

Alternatively if you're sure you followed the specs of the webservice correctly, the only thing you can do is proper error handling, that is, if the server returns an error for your request (codes 400 to 499) to not process further the return value but just signal the error condition.

Answer (score 0):

This XML is invalid for webservice you use.

Paste it here: http://wl.filos.com.gr/services/WebService.asmx?op=PlaceSearch and check what is wrong

Comment: $xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap12:Body><PlaceSearch xmlns="http://www.cyberlogic.gr/webservices/"><xml><PlaceSearchRequest><Username>SERUNCD</Username><Password>TA78UNC</Password><PlaceType>Cities</PlaceType><Language>en</Language></PlaceSearchRequest></xml></PlaceSearch></soap12:Body></soap12:Envelope>';

Comment: now gets error 400
can you help me
http://agency.lastminute-hr.com/stranice/upisi_destinacije_unico.php

Comment: So it is still invalid. Correct it

Comment: I do not get where the error in XML

Comment: hmm, check differences between documentation and your result. Paste your xml and xml from doc (http://wl.filos.com.gr/services/WebService.asmx?op=PlaceSearch) here: https://www.diffchecker.com/diff and try to do it identical

Comment: The two files are identical

Comment: including white characters?

Comment: yeah, I do not get what's the error ..

Comment: `Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.` You can test it at documentation page. Paste your request there

Comment: $xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$xml_post_string .= '<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">';
$xml_post_string .= '<soap12:Body>';
$xml_post_string .= '<PlaceSearch xmlns="http://www.cyberlogic.gr/webservices/">';

$xml_post_string .='</PlaceSearch>';
$xml_post_string .='</soap12:Body>';
$xml_post_string .='</soap12:Envelope>';